# Integrate a media-player into Nautilus file browser

Tags: nautilus, multimedia

I wish to integrate Gnome MPlayer with Nautilus file browser.
You know, add:

- "Play with MPlayer"
- "Enqueue to MPlayer"

Couldn't find how to do this.
I just want for MP3 and other relevant music files to have a "play/add" option.
And for directories (regardless of contents" to also have a "play/add" option.

Would appreciate your help.
David:)

Comment: Do you use any GUI frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this [link](http://techthrob.com/2009/03/02/howto-add-items-to-the-right-click-menu-in-nautilus/) will show you how to add to the right click menu in nautilus; then all you have to do is write the script that adds and plays a song with MPlayer.

Let me know if this works out for you. I got it working here.

Comment: Smooth man! Looks original, I also chose an icon, and it all looks factory-made. 10x :)